# Error trying to customize Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I have just changed to using the appcompat theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">


        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>


    </style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/orange</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/orange</item>

    </style>
```

I am importing the AppCompat libs in build.xml

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+"
```

So why is this error below happening?

```
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar'.
```

From [these docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style) it appears it should work.

Comment: What level is your build target set to?

Comment: currently 19 but I did also try setting it to 21 and I still had the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that when using support libraries one should ommit the `android:` prefix. So just try:

```
Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar
```

**Edit:**

As I've said, for support themes you need to ommit `android:`. That means everywhere:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="background">@color/orange</item>
</style>
```

This is all nicely pointed out [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground).

Comment: That at least got rid of the error. Granted the correct color is still not getting used. Any quick ideas there?

Comment: It looks like the reason the color is not being used is because I am using api-21 appcompat which I think (I may be wrong) requires me to use ToolBar instead of actionbar.

Comment: Its not that "nicely" pointed out in the docs. It says for 3.1 and higher and then shows the inclusion of the android: prefix.

Comment: @startoftext I should have written nicely in quotes ^^ Android documentation can be really cryptic.